# volume group problem for booting

Tags: boot, lvm

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 newly into ASUS model 502V notebook where window 10 resided originally with an option of encryption and LVM with DVD ROM. After normal operation thereafter,  I got the following display message once had tried to boot the system.

---

```
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
volume group "ubuntu-vg" not found.
Cannot process volume group ubuntu-vg
WARNING: failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning. 
Reading all physical volumes. This may take a while...
Found volume group "ubuntu-vg" using metadata type lvm2
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
2 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu-vg" now active
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg--root: clean, 188107/7675904 files, 3234687/30682112 blocks
```

---

It's my knowledge that CMOS has USB option for booting.
Previously it appeared there so that I managed to set the priority properly.
However this time I can't get the usb option after tried to reboot or plugging in external DVD ROM or USB. There displays only the residing ubuntu(P0: ..... ) in any case. It doesn't return to reboot function. How to get in to have new boot option in CMOS environment? It doesn't matter either to use existing P0 or new boot? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know or not know what you are doing when it comes encryption? I gotta admit first time I ever switched to linux I saw that : http://www.cim.mcgill.ca/~anqixu/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/ubuntu_crypto1.png and I though, "damn that looks sexy let's try it out!", ten years later, as a more experienced ubuntu user, I wouldn't for the life of me be able to come up with a good reason to use this for a computer that's going to be personal (only used by one person) and also won't be used for transfering military data. honestly I could be a fugitive cybercriminal and I still wouldn't

Comment: basically : is redoing the installation not an option?

Comment: For security reason I chose the encryption following a guide. I've looked through google search. There most of the cases seemed to be possible to reboot. But I can't.

Comment: well windows is what's messing with thing here, it introduces a whole lot of unknowns, you have know if windows is in Legacy/UEFI mode and same for our ubuntu, you have to first disable fast boot in the bios and in windows, inside an admin powershell type `powercfg -h off`. try this then try installing again. what's likely happening is that windows is messing with your ability to write to the drive when it's not booted. And encryption boot, fragile as it is, needs everything to be perfect.

Comment: It needed patience, finally solved the issue. Thanks.